# Why is "use client" context giving me "Module parse failed: Invalid escape sequence" in Next js?

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJwIY.png)

I have been trying add next auth in my nextjs 13 project and i am passing session from the layout to providers.ts with client context but it gives me this error. I am using getserversession but to no avail and now i am stuck

Comment: Hi, and welcome! Please create a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.